# Accessing global variables in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

Learning react here!

I'm trying to access a global variable that is exposed by a browser extension that I'm utilizing. The first thing that I'm doing is in the `componentDidMount` method I'm checking to see if the variable is available or not.

Every time I try to do that by simply adding an if condition in `componentDidMount` it fails.  But if I wrap the if statement in

```
document.onreadystatechange = () => {
       if (document.readyState === 'complete') {
```

it works fine. I thought that the `componentDidMount` would have done the trick rather than wrapping my condition check in the code above.

Am I missing something here?  Is there a better way to check if the app has completely rendered and it will have access to the global variables provided by the browser?

Thanks!

Comment: componentDidMount is called after your component has been mounted, if you are not sure when your global variable is going to exposed then you should add a condition to check it is exposed or not.

Comment: if your recieve props after rendering of that component, may be you can use ```componentDidUpdate``` to access the variable

Comment: The document is definitely ready if a react component has mounted. "The app has rendered" depends on your definition of what that is, React apps re-render all the time, `componentDidMount` should be a sufficient check

Answer (score 0):

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/reactjs/reactjs_component_life_cycle.htm

> componentDidUpdate

may work for you.

Comment: It's taking about 3 seconds to gain the readyState that why this happening.